# Why can't I dim a variable as `Application.WorksheetFunction`?

Tags: vba

Why does this work:

```
Dim WF as WorksheetFunction
```

But this doesn't work?

```
Dim WF as Application.WorksheetFunction
```

For some reason adding the library qualifier, which should be more descriptive, causes a type mismatch.  Unlike both of these working:

```
Dim dic1 as Dictionary
Dim dic1 as Scripting.Dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out.  It looks like WorksheetFunction is actually a member of the Excel library, but a property of the Application Object